# Use the Culture of the OS, but not the language

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, culture

I've encountered several times the same problem in applications we develop:

We want to allow the user to edit/display it's data in his format (date, currency, ...), but we want to display the application in English only (for several reasons, it's a pro, international application, in a domain in which we communicate mostly in English).

There is no problem when we manage the whole application, but most of third-party pro frameworks that I used (Telerik, DevExpress) are using the `CurrentCulture` to display my data in the correct format AND in the corresponding language.

So, even if I have my computer in English, I have my regional settings set to `fr-CH`, I will have all third party user controls in French.

I cannot set the `CurrentCulture` to a specific culture and set the format of my user controls to something else (I would loose my default format) and I can't let the `CurrentCulture` to be the default one because I would have my third party components in another language.

I tried to build my own culture (`CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder`), with no success. When I change the language, I still have my application in the user-specific language.

**Concrete problem**

I'm using a date editor(basic, it has one text input and can popup a calendar). I want to have the date displayed in my OS locale(ch-FR, so 15 january 2013 would be "15.01.2013"), but I don't want that when I display the calendar month/day name appears in french.

What is the correct approach with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by having a custom culture info:

```
private static void UpdateCultureInfoWithoutLangage()
{
    //We initialize a en-US cultureInfo and change all formats + number infor related
    CultureInfo cultureInfoEn = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    CultureInfo cultureInfoEnClone = (CultureInfo)cultureInfoEn.Clone();

    //Setting DateTimeFormat(Without changing translations)
    cultureInfoEnClone.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
    cultureInfoEnClone.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern;
    cultureInfoEnClone.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
    cultureInfoEnClone.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern;
    cultureInfoEnClone.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern;
    cultureInfoEnClone.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
    cultureInfoEnClone.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
    cultureInfoEnClone.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator;
    cultureInfoEnClone.DateTimeFormat.YearMonthPattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.YearMonthPattern;
    cultureInfoEnClone.NumberFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfoEnClone;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfoEnClone;
    Application.CurrentCulture = cultureInfoEnClone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the original `CultureInfo` for your purposes and try editing `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` properties of the `CurrentThread` property in `System.Threading.Thread`, maybe this will solve your problem.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: Doesn't work, either my userControl will be in french, either its default format will be in english

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand your problem. Do you want the input to be in one culture and the page in another culture?!?

Comment: @Sandman I added a concrete problem, it may help to understand. But the want to have my DateTime displayed with correct format, but GUI tools which have some texts related to my input(calendar, ...) displayed in english